# Setting up EOS private Multi Host Network

Tags: private-blockchain

I have already Deployed 1 eos node. I want my other 2 servers to sync with this node ( creating a network). Kindly guide me what should be changed regarding genesis.json ( chainId? , publickey? ) and p2p listen , p2p peer in config.ini.

I figured out these fields can be channged to make them synced but I need someone to Explain EACH and EVERYTHING pretty Clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a guide on biosboot sequence in [EOSIO developer portal](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence) and I think you will find it useful understanding such configurations.

The `p2p-listen-address` field indicates which IP address and port will be opened  for other peers to communicate with this certain node. Think of it as a server address.

On the other hand, the `p2p-peer-address` field indicates the other nodes' address and port this node should communicate with. In this case, you can think of it as your node being a client reaching for other nodes that serves as server.

One node does not have to be directly in sync with block producing node, but there must be at least one indirect connection with block producing node to make oneself useful and utilize the EOSIO network.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I totally get your pont. I have looked at that part ( you mentioned ). For my other 2 nodes ( which you called as client nides ) to validate the transactions, what should I do ? Where should I store their EOSIO accounts keys? Either in their own wallets or in the node#1 ( which you called server node ) ? How will they validate. I got the p2p thing you explained and you did it perfectly. Thank you for that but its confusing me that how will they validate transanctions, should I launch client nodes with the same genesis.json ( and pointing the chain id in that as the ch